# How to add newline with gsub in logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

I have a field 'message'.

When I do this : `mutate { 
                   update => {"message" => "%{message} \n"}
                }`

It converts message to: `"2017-12-31 Error \\n"` ["2017-12-31 Error" is my message value]

What I want is `"2017-12-31 Error \n"`

Also tried to figure out using below links, but could not find a solution:

[Add newline with gsub](https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-985)

[Define quote escaping semantics.](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/1645)

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me, was to add an actual line break (although it looks a bit silly):

```
mutate {
    update => {"message" => "%{message} 
"}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found one solution, feel free to add other solutions also:

```
ruby {
      # Add a \n (newline) by using its ASCII code (10)
      code => "event.set('message', event.get('message') + ' ' + 10.chr)"
}
```